# How to access values in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json, object

This question has been asked before, however, the current answers don't solve my problem. When console.log-ing the value I am trying to grab from my object (an object retrieved from JSON) I get back some sort of

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'approximateGroup' of undefined"

the JSON data is assigned to a var named rxcui and consists of the following:

```
{"approximateGroup":{"inputTerm":"paxil","maxEntries":"1","option":"0","comment":"","candidate":
[{"rxcui":"114228","rxaui":"826081","score":"100","rank":"1"},
{"rxcui":"114228","rxaui":"826082","score":"100","rank":"1"},
{"rxcui":"114228","rxaui":"8053434","score":"100","rank":"1"}]}}
```

and my code is

```
console.log(rxcui.[0].approximateGroup.candidate[0].rxcui);
```

I have tried inspecting the object in my browser, copying the path and using every combination I could possibly think to for the last few hours. I understand that if I get a return of undefined then my path is wrong, but this is what path makes sense. The exact path my browser tells me its at is:

```
[0].approximateGroup.candidate[0].rxcui
```

I've tried finding the path in the success function jquery for the JSON page as well with no success.

Please help, I'm going insane :+)

Comment: is the path `rxcui[0].approximateGroup.candidate[0]` or `[0].approximateGroup.candidate[0].rxcui` ?

Comment: the latter is what chrome tells me the correct path is, however when used I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'candidate' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Your first property is the object *approximateGroup*, then you can acess the candidate array indicating the first index, then you acess the rxcui property of this object.

```
console.log(YourOBJ.approximateGroup.candidate[0].rxcui)
```

Comment: you cant start with [0] because is not a array, its a object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your json in a more readable format

```
{
  "approximateGroup": {
    "inputTerm": "paxil",
    "maxEntries": "1",
    "option": "0",
    "comment": "",
    "candidate": [
      {
        "rxcui": "114228",
        "rxaui": "826081",
        "score": "100",
        "rank": "1"
      },
      {
        "rxcui": "114228",
        "rxaui": "826082",
        "score": "100",
        "rank": "1"
      },
      {
        "rxcui": "114228",
        "rxaui": "8053434",
        "score": "100",
        "rank": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`rxcui` is a property of an object within the `candidate` array. The `candidate` array is a property within the `approximategroup` object.

If we assign the json to a variable `x` then you can address it in this way

`const firstRxcuit = x.approximateGroup.candidate[0].rxcui`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up array and object notation, you cant use [Int] by index in an object, only an array, you can however use ["some prop"] against an object to find a value of a property

```js
    var rxcui  = {"approximateGroup":{"inputTerm":"paxil","maxEntries":"1","option":"0","comment":"","candidate":
    [{"rxcui":"114228","rxaui":"826081","score":"100","rank":"1"},
    {"rxcui":"114228","rxaui":"826082","score":"100","rank":"1"},
    {"rxcui":"114228","rxaui":"8053434","score":"100","rank":"1"}]}}
    
    
    
    console.log(rxcui.approximateGroup.candidate[0].rxaui) // returns "826081"
```